# Allow user to create and alter table?

Tags: mysql

I have a current mysql user who has `SELECT` privileges for all the table in database `example`. How can give that user privileges to add new tables, and alter/add records to the table it created?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the grant keyword combined with the table privileges you seek to give the user.

```
GRANT ALTER, CREATE ON example TO 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

[MySQL Grant](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html)

[MySQL Table Privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-table-privileges)

Answer (score 2):

`GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE ON database TO username@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

You can use UPDATE in the list too.

Comment: Missing CREATE privilege - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/privileges-provided.html

Comment: @Skydreamer But i dont want to allow him to insert, delete on the existing tables, only on the tables he create

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `example` .  * TO 'user'@'%';

This gives all the privileges for ONLY the 'example' database to user

Comment: That wont work for me because i dont want him to be aloud to alter existing tables in the database

Answer (score -1):

Old; but just because it comes first when you query about "mysql grants to create table"
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, ALTER, LOCK TABLES, SHOW VIEW ON `database`.* TO 'user'@'host'