# Selecting a database in PHP/SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, xampp

```
// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE unpw (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table unpw created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}
```

I'm new to both SQL and PHP and have been working on converting some python and `C++` code to PHP with an SQL server for a project of mine, and it's throwing an error saying there

"`Error creating table: No database selected`" (thank you error handling).

How do I select a database?

I've tried editing it to say:

```
$sql = "USE myDB;
CREATE TABLE unpw (
```

Etc, but I get the error:

`"Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE unpw ( id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, username' at line 2"`

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Does this DB user have create table privileges? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113789/allow-user-to-create-and-alter-table

Comment: $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "";

Comment: so yes! I hope so at least.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your $servername to this?

```
$servername  = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDb"
```

Comment: Is your MySql server on your localhost? If it is on another server you should change the "localhost" for the Ip adress of the server.

Comment: Yeah, it's on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

add this to the top, change the details with yours

```
$DBServer = 'server name or IP address'; // e.g 'localhost' or '192.168.1.100'
$DBUser   = 'DB_USER';
$DBPass   = 'DB_PASSWORD';
$DBName   = 'DB_NAME';

$conn = new mysqli($DBServer, $DBUser, $DBPass, $DBName);
```

Comment: "Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in I:\Programs\XAMPP\htdocs\example\helloWorld.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in I:\Programs\XAMPP\htdocs\example\helloWorld.php on line 10
Connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known."