# How to add a new column in MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

How to add a new column in MySQL using PHP? I tried to do it many hours, but I can not solve my issue. Code:

```
<?php
$DB_HOST = "localhost";
$DB_USER  = "xxxxxx";
$DB_PASSWORD = "xxxxxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxxxxx";
$connect = mysql_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD);
$db="test_table";
if (! $connect)
die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db , $connect) or die("Select Error: ".mysql_error());

$result=mysql_query("ALTER TABLE id
ADD street VARCHAR(30) AFTER birthday,
Add city VARCHAR(30) AFTER street,
ADD state VARCHAR(4) AFTER city,
ADD zipcode VARCHAR(20) AFTER state,
ADD phone VARCHAR(20) AFTER zipcode") or die("Alter Error: ".mysql_error());
mysql_close($connect);
print "Field added";
?>
```

When I test this code an error appears:

> Select Error: Access denied for user 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'@'localhost' to database 'test_table'

How can I do that?

Comment: The User (see connect.php) needs the privilege to Alter the table.

Answer (score 1):

First be sure your user has the right privileges as described in [this so question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7113868/1814739)

Probably need to run some mysql like this:

`GRANT ALTER ON example_table TO 'someuser'@'somehost';`

Then similar code to the following should work.

```
<?php

    $db = new mysqli('localhost','USERNAME','PASSWORD','DATABASENAME');

    $sql = '
        ALTER TABLE id
        ADD street VARCHAR(30) AFTER birthday,
        Add city VARCHAR(30) AFTER street,
        ADD state VARCHAR(4) AFTER city,
        ADD zipcode VARCHAR(20) AFTER state,
        ADD phone VARCHAR(20) AFTER zipcode';

    try {
        $r = $db->prepare($sql);
        $r->execute();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        error_log(print_r($e->getMessage(),1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL user do not have access to your database, but you can connect to your MySQL server (it gives back an error message) and login there.

This means, that the user is not privileged to use your database `test_table`, please check again the database name (in your example, you give a table name, make sure you are using the database name and not a table name!). Also, you can try it with root account, if it is your server.

This is not a problem of your code but of authentification. Make sure you use the correct information.

Comment: this user make all privileged.

Comment: @robertqewerutiyo: This cannot be. The error message says this clearly.