# Is there a way to lock schema (only) on MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want get consistent schema snapshot.

To do that, I want make sure that ensure other session does not execute DDL (alter etc) during my transaction.

Is there any way to that STOP concurrent DDL during specific period?

Note: I know that `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` satisfies the purpose, but I cannot use it because it affects other DML transactions.

Comment: Disallow the answer given here: [Allow user to create and alter table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113789/allow-user-to-create-and-alter-table) to everyone but yourself.

Comment: I do not intended to disallow it completely. Just lock = wait other session DDL.

Comment: You should not change your schema so frequently that this is a REAL problem. If you are working in a team, then stop your team-members from changing the schema, and create a snapshot, if this is not a team situation, then ..... can you provide more details?

Comment: Imagine you have a batch to need lock schema. And another batch executes DDL for create/delete temporary table. If those are runs concurrently (because some batch delay), miserable things happen.